# Как вместо точки сделать запятую в цене?

Tags: php, modx, revo

как можно изменить цену в modx revo, вместо разделения цены точки (4.45 руб.), сделать запятую (4,45 руб.)?

Использую miniShop2. Для вывода цены в title определенной категории использую данный код:

```
[[!msProducts? &parents=`[[*id]]` &limit=`1` &tpl=`@INLINE [[+price]]` &sortby=`Data.price`]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MODX есть модификаторы, но в вашем случае лучше, чтобы они сработали внутри чанка, а именно:

```
[[!msProducts? &parents=`[[*id]]` &limit=`1` &tpl=`priceTpl` &sortby=`Data.price`]]
```

а в *priceTpl*:

```
[[+price:replace=.==,]]
```

В данном случае модификатор использует как раз функции замены строк PHP.

Также обратите внимание на системную переменную *ms2_price_format* в minishop2

Answer (score 0):

С помощью любой функции для замены подстрок, например [strtr()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php):

```
$str = '4.45 руб';

$str = strtr($str, '.', ',');

echo $str;
```